# Configure default error handler to commit messages after recovery

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I would like to retry consuming a message on processing/deserialiation failure for a finite number of times. After the retries are exhausted, I would like to log a message, commit the offset and move ahead with consuming further messages. For this to happen I have configured the error handler bean as below.

I am using the ack mode as MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and the auto commit is disabled by `enable.auto.commit: false` 
Offsets are committed manually/programmatically with a reference to an Acknowledgement object (ack.acknowledge())

EDIT: As per Gary's comments, I have edited the config of error handler

```
@Bean
public DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler(){

   ConsumerRecordRecoverer recovery = (record, ex) ->{
   
      log.error("Retries have been exhausted. Commiting offset "+record.offset())
    }
  
   // Default backoff
   BackOff backoff = new FixedBackOff(3000, 5);
   DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(recovery, backoff);
   defaultErrorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
   defaultErrorHandler.setAckAfterHandle(true);

  // BackOff to use when HttpServerException occurs
     BackOff infiniteRetry = new FixedBackOff(FixedBackOff.DEFAULT_INTERVAL, FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS);

  BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?,?>,Exception, BackOff> backOffFunction = (record, ex) -> {
  
  if(ex instanceOf HttpServerException){
      return infiniteRetry;
     }
    return null;
  }
   defaultErrorHandler.removeClassification(DeserializationException.class);
   defaultErrorHandler.setBackOffFunction(backOffFunction)
   return defaultErrorHandler;
}
```

Questions:

1. In the case when retries(5) have been exhausted, the idea is to log a message and commit the offset and move forward with consuming other messages. For this to happen, I have configured the below on the error handler. Please confirm if this is enough?

```
defaultErrorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
defaultErrorHandler.setAckAfterHandle(true);
```

2. Since the DesrializationExeption is part of the fatal list, it's not going to be retried. Therefore I configured the error handler to remove it this way for a retry to occur as configured, when a Deserialization error occurs. Please confirm if this is correct?

`defaultErrorHandler.removeClassification(DeserializationException.class);`

3. Is there a way to configure a retry policy for a given exception ? For example, retry consuming a message infinitely on a Database non availability error. This was possible in earlier versions of Springboot/Spring-kafka, as the retry policy can be set on the Listener Container. However, I could not figure this in the latest version. Please help me with any sample if its possible.

Note: I have tried the above config and it seems to work. I would like to verify with the experts that this config does what is expected and does not cause any other effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, everything is correctly configured.

> Is there a way to configure a retry policy for a given exception ? For example, retry consuming a message infinitely on a Database non availability error.

See

```java
/**
 * Set a function to dynamically determine the {@link BackOff} to use, based on the
 * consumer record and/or exception. If null is returned, the default BackOff will be
 * used.
 * @param backOffFunction the function.
 * @since 2.6
 */
public void setBackOffFunction(BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, BackOff> backOffFunction) {
```

also

```java
/**
 * Set to true to reset the retry {@link BackOff} if the exception is a different type
 * to the previous failure for the same record. The
 * {@link #setBackOffFunction(BiFunction) backOffFunction}, if provided, will be
 * called to get the {@link BackOff} to use for the new exception; otherwise, the
 * configured {@link BackOff} will be used. Default true since 2.9; set to false
 * to use the existing retry state, even when exceptions change.
 * @param resetStateOnExceptionChange true to reset.
 * @since 2.6.3
 */
public void setResetStateOnExceptionChange(boolean resetStateOnExceptionChange) {
```

(It is now true by default).

Comment: Please check the edited code snippet. I configured the error handler to have a back off function which allows infinite retries when HttpServerException occurs. The idea is to use backoff that's supplied to the DefaultErrorHandler while it's initialized, for all exceptions that aren't HttpServerException. Custom BackOff is created using a BiFunction and is set on the defaultErrorHandler object. Please let me know if the backoff supplied to the DefaultErrorHandler's constructor is treated as default one and will be used when the Bifuncation returns null.

Comment: Yes; but why do you need confirmation? That's exactly what the javadoc says. However, you don't need to create a new `BackOff` each time the function is called; just create it once alongside the default `BackOff` and return it from the function.